# Cannot add foreign key SQL fiddle

Tags: sql, fiddle

Im new to sql, I'm having issues with the foreign key in my table. If any can point out the error, please do, I have no idea what it is.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJdl7.png)

```
CREATE TABLE donut(
  donutId int(5) NOT NULL, 
  name VARCHAR(20), 
  descriptioin VARCHAR(60), 
  price DECIMAL(8,3), 
  PRIMARY KEY (donutId) 
);

CREATE TABLE customer(
customerid INT(5)NOT NULL,
firstname VARCHAR(30),
lastname VARCHAR(30), 
addres VARCHAR(100),
apt VARCHAR(20),
city VARCHAR(30),
state VARCHAR(20),    
zip VARCHAR(8),
homephone  VARCHAR(15),          
cellphone  VARCHAR(15),
otherphone VARCHAR(15),
PRIMARY KEY (customerid) );

CREATE TABLE customer_order_donut(
orderid int(10) NOT NULL,
customerid int(10),
donutId int(10), 
orderdate datetime,
donutqty INT(5),
specialhandling TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY (orderid) 
customerid int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES customer(customerid),
donutId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES donut(donutId));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your FOREIGNKEY syntax is wrong. This should work:

```
CREATE TABLE donut
(
  donutid      INT(5) NOT NULL,
  name         VARCHAR(20),
  descriptioin VARCHAR(60),
  price        DECIMAL(8,3),
  PRIMARY KEY (donutid)
);
CREATE TABLE customer
(
  customerid INT(5)NOT NULL,
  firstname  VARCHAR(30),
  lastname   VARCHAR(30),
  addres     VARCHAR(100),
  apt        VARCHAR(20),
  city       VARCHAR(30),
  state      VARCHAR(20),
  zip        VARCHAR(8),
  homephone  VARCHAR(15),
  cellphone  VARCHAR(15),
  otherphone VARCHAR(15),
  PRIMARY KEY (customerid)
);
CREATE TABLE customer_order_donut
(
  orderid    INT(10) NOT NULL,
  customerid INT(10),
  donutid    INT(10),
  orderdate  DATETIME,
  donutqty   INT(5),
  specialhandling TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (orderid),
  FOREIGN KEY (customerid) REFERENCES customer(customerid),
  FOREIGN KEY (donutid) REFERENCES donut(donutid)
);
```

Comment: Hi, have you spotted any issues with my answer that you didn't like and thought you should provide yours?

Comment: I'm working on project  now I got stuck on another error, Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails. INSERT INTO customer_order_donut (orderid, customerid, donutid, orderdate,donutqty,specialhandling) VALUES ('141','101','251','2010-10-11','14','In Rush');
INSERT INTO customer_order_donut (orderid, customerid, donutid, orderdate,donutqty,specialhandling) VALUES ('151','111','326','2010-10-61','12','No Coffe');
INSERT INTO customer_order_donut (orderid, customerid, donutid, orderdate,donutqty,specialhandling) VALUES ('161','121','235','2010-10-91','15','No Hurry');

Answer (score 0):

Check the [syntax of the FOREIGN KEY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) constraints (and add a comma after PRIMARY KEY):

```
CREATE TABLE customer_order_donut(
orderid int(10) NOT NULL,
customerid int(10),
donutId int(10), 
orderdate datetime,
donutqty INT(5),
specialhandling TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY (orderid),
FOREIGN KEY (customerid) REFERENCES customer(customerid),
FOREIGN KEY (donutid) REFERENCES donut(donutId)
);
```

Comment: You are welcome! Perhaps you should consider accepting the answer, so that other users could benefit as well.